# How to test Angular component that conditionally renders a <div> with *ngIf?

Tags: angular, jestjs, components

I have a component that conditionally renders a div

```
<div *ngIf="shouldRender" id="info-banner">
 <p>The info is shown</p>
</div>
```

The test looks like this

```
it('should display the info') , () => {
   spectator = createComponent()
   spectator.setInput( { shouldRender:true})
   spectator.detectChanges()
   const infoBanner = spectator.query("#info-banner")
   expect(infoBanner).toBeTruthy()
})
```

The test always fails, why?

Comment: what does the fail message say? Can you show the testbed configuration as well?

Comment: That´s pretty much it. The spectator.query() is returning null. Shouldn´t it be returning the identified <div> ? 
I´ve tested the setting of the 'shouldRender' flag and it works. I can set/reset it on the test script and it detects the change accordingly.

Comment: so `infoBanner` is not truthy. I guess the spectator query does not work liek that. Can you try `spectator.query(byTestId('info-banner'));` instead?

Comment: Tried it, byTestId() undefined

Answer (score 0):

Can you adjust the following code at the `MyComponent` occurances and give feedback what the test failmessage is exactly saying?

```
import {
    byTestId, createComponentFactory, Spectator
} from '@ngneat/spectator';

describe('MyComponent with spectator', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<MyComponent>; // adjust MyComponent with your component

    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
        component: MyComponent, // adjust MyComponent with your component
        shallow: true,
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        spectator = createComponent({ props: {shouldRender: true}});
    });

    it('should display the info if shouldRender is true', () => {
        expect(
            spectator.query(byTestId('info-banner'))
        ).toBeTruthy;
    });
});
```